# Matlab, accesing elements in vector

Tags: matlab, loops, vector

I have two vectors, one which stores x coordinates and one which stores y coordinates. When I try to access them in the loop, it is returning the same coordinates in every iteration of the loop.

Can anyone help me fix my loop please?

```
 N2=8;
         info2 = repmat(struct, ceil(size(Z, 1) / N2), ceil(size(Z, 2) / N2)); %creates another array of structs consisting of an m-by-n tiling
         for row1 = 1:N2:size(Z, 1)%loop through each pixel in the 8x8 window
             for col1 = 1:N2:size(Z, 2)
                 x = (row1 - 1) / N2 + 1;
                 y = (col1 - 1) / N2 + 1;

                 imgWindow2 = Z(row1:min(end,row1+N2-1), col1:min(end,col1+N2-1));
                 average2 = mean(imgWindow2(:)); 
                 window2(x,y).average=average2;


                % if the intensity of the 8x8 window is greater than
                % 210 then considered suspicious- calculate GLCM-
                 if average2>100
                    % display('greater than 100');

                %best direction is 0
                    offsets0 = [0 1];
                     glcms = graycomatrix(imgWindow2,'Offset',offsets0);
                     stats = graycoprops(glcms,'all'); %normalize GLCM so that values are between 0 and 1

                    correlation=[stats.Correlation];  
                    contrast=[stats.Contrast];
                    homogeneity=[stats.Homogeneity];
                    energy=[stats.Energy];


                    %if these conditions are met then this window
                    %contains an ROI
                    if (homogeneity > 0.9)
                        if  (contrast<0.2)
                            if (energy>0.6)


                                for i=1:length(coordsX)
                                    coordsX(i)=row1;
                                   for j=1:length(coordsY)
                                    coordsY(j)=col1;
                                   end
                                end                                                                                                


                               for ii=1:length(coordsX)
                               coX=coordsX(ii);
                                for jj=1: length(coordsY)
                                  coY=coordsY(jj)
                                  Z1  = insertShape(Z, 'rectangle', [coX coY 8 8]);
                                  figure(2);
                                 end
                                end 


                            end
                        end
                    end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your nested `for` loops:

1. You use the same index `i` twice, so you are resetting the value of the outermost loop index within the loop, never a good idea
2. Your innermost loop indexes into `coordsX`, but inside the loop you access `coordsY`. Here, you're lucky as `coordsX` and `coordsY` appear to have the same size. Most of the time, you would get an error though.

Suggested fix:

```
for ii=1:length(coordsX)
    coX=coordsX(ii);
    for jj=1: length(coordsY)
        coY=coordsY(jj)
        Z1  = insertShape(Z, 'rectangle', [coX coY 8 8]);
        figure(2);
    end
end
```

Note that I have used `ii` and `jj` as indices instead of `i` and `j`, which are normally used for complex numbers in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this fix but only one rectangle is appearing on the image. The image opens several times with the rectangle in the same place position each time. Do you know how I can show the one image with multiple rectangles on it for each of the coordinates?

Comment: Probably needs to also use `hold on` to make sure the previous rectangle remains on the plot.

Comment: ok thanks. However all x and y coords in the array are the same value.

Comment: well, that's a different issue, which is based on how you generate your `x` and `y` coordinates. I have no idea about this, and you don't really provide enough information on how the data is generated.

Comment: citation of matlab: "replace complex i and j with 1i for increased speed and robustness". So using i or j does not do so much damage if good practice with complex numbers is followed. Also, since `coordsX` have the same length as `coordsY` this does no damage either (even if it is recommended to use the size of the used vector). I would guess that the only problems was that `i` was used in 2 loops and that `hold on` was missing. Given that `Z` and the coordinate vectors is correct so to say.

Comment: I have updated my question  so that you can see exactly how the data is generated